# Как конвертировать строку в дату

Tags: python, datetime

Есть строка

```
a = '24 июля 2021 г.'
```

Как ее конвертировать в дату (чтоб тип переменной был дата) и в формат '07/24/2021'

Пыталась использовать возможности библиотеки datetime, но она не работает с русскими названиями месяцев

```
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%d %B %Y')
```

этот код выдает ошибку

```
ValueError: time data '24 июля 2021 г.' does not match format '%d %B %Y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить локаль и почистить дату - убрать 'г.' и изменить падежное окончание месяца.

```
import datetime
import locale

a = '24 июля 2021 г.'

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "ru_RU")
right_a = a.replace('г.', '').replace('июля', 'июль').strip()
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(right_a, '%d %B %Y')
print(date_time_obj.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

```
07/24/2021
```

Comment: кажется оно работает даже с месяцем в родительном падеже) благодарю)